# Getting posts (poster name, photo, text body) into VF page from specific Chatter group - Struggling getting into VF

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

I am working off of some code I found on the Internet - I have only been on the ADM 201 course.

What I am doing is attempting to pull the information from a post and then put this into a VF page. I know I can use chatter:feed, but this is getting all of the information and functions, whereas I need only the text body, poster name, and picture (not essential).

What I have so far:

Apex Class:

```
    public class Test_3 {        //Class is 
public ConnectApi.FeedElementPage feedElementPage{get;set;}
public Test_3() {
    feedElementPage =    ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementsFromFeed('0F958000000TWvL',   ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, 'showInternalOnly');
    }
    }
```

VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="Test_5">
   <div class="posts">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <apex:repeat value="{!feed.elements}" var="feedElement">
            <div class="media">
                <a class="pull-left" href="{!feedElement.parent.id}">
                <img class="media-object" src="{!feedElement.photoUrl}" alt="{!feedElement.actor.name}"/>
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">{!feedItem.actor.name}</h4>
                        // This creates a heading from the posts that is the poster's name
                        {!feedElement.body.text}
                        // This is the body of the post
                        </div>
                    </div>
       </apex:repeat>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

```
 <footer>
    <p>&copy; Operations Updates - Please refresh your browser for the latest</p>
 </footer>
</apex:page>
```

Current issues:

- !feedElement.parent.id
- !feedItem.actor.name
- "Error: Unknown property 'ConnectApi.Feed.elements'"

Anyway, I can't work this out. I've been trying to make this for a lovely 5 hours now.

Any help would be much appreciated.

The code was modified from [here](http://appirio.com/category/tech-blog/2014/01/chatter-apex/) and then I attempted to update it to Elements from Items.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your Apex class, the variable is called "feedElementPage" but in the Visualforce page, it says "feed". Please update `feedElementPage` to `feed` in Apex class or update `repeat value="{!feed.elements}"` to `repeat value="{!feedElementPage.elements}"`

In addition, I think you should use [FeedItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_feed_element.htm) instead of [FeedElement](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_feed_element.htm). Please take a look at the document, and let me know if you have any other questions.